# How to process CSV data from two files using a matching column

Tags: ruby, csv

I have two CSV files, one is 3.5GB and the other one is 100MB. The larger file contains two columns that I need to add to two other columns from the other file to make a third CSV file.

Both files contain a postcode column which is how I'm trying to match the rows from them. However, as the files are quite large, the operation is slow. I tried looking for matches in two ways but they were both slow:

```
CSV.foreach('ukpostcodes.csv') do |row|
  CSV.foreach('pricepaid.csv') do |item|
    if row[1] == item[3]
      puts "match"
    end
  end
end
```

and:

```
firstFile = CSV.read('pricepaid.csv')
secondFile = CSV.read('ukpostcodes.csv')

post_codes = Array.new
lat_longs = Array.new

firstFile.each do |row|
  post_codes << row[3]
end

secondFile.each do |row|
  lat_longs << row[1]
end

post_codes.each do |row|
  lat_longs.each do |item|
    if row == item
      puts "Match"
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a more efficient way of handling this task as the CSV files are large in size?

Comment: your first one is doing a "cartesian join" - for every row in the uk file, cross-reference to ALL rows in the price file that means you're doing `N x M` equality tests. The second one does just as many joins/comparisons, minus not having to store the entire row in memory. You would be FAR better off stuffing both files into a proper database and doing a conventional `join`.

Comment: Would it be considerably faster to put both files into seperate tables and do a join on them instead ?

Comment: the second one would be a wee bit more efficient, since you only load the  uk file **ONCE** instead of every single time you process a new row of the other file. but either way, you're doing NxM comparisons. if that's 1 million records in the 3.5gig file and 10,000 records in the 100meg file, that's 10 BILLION comparisons

Comment: That's what I'd do too. Postgres has pretty good support for importing CSVs, pgfutter makes this a breeze, you then have a tool that is pretty much tailor-made to do all sorts of joins and transformations on your data.

Comment: The 3rd csv that was meant to be produced was going to be processed by a php script to be handed to a mysql database. Would it make a difference whether it's mysql or postgres?

Comment: Not sure of the specifics, but I think any good RDBMS should be able to do this. There might not be the same tools or tools I'm used to work with, but Mysql ought to be able to do this.

Comment: I agree that a good DB is the right solution. PostgreSQL and MySQL are free to use and are made to handle massive amounts of data and can easily import CSV files. Sequel is a good ORM if you're writing in plain-Ruby, otherwise ActiveRecord in Rails would be a good choice.

Comment: @MarcB If you post an answer I will accept it since i decided to follow your advice and put the files into a database.